# Get all available combinations of two fields through the Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have this Django model:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    lecture_number = models.CharField(_('lecture number'), max_length=20)
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=100)
    term = models.IntegerField(_('term'), choices=TERM, db_index=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(_('year'), db_index=True)
```

`term` can be either `1` or `2` (spring or fall). Now I want to list all terms for which there are lectures, e.g. something like `((2007, 2), (2008, 1), (2008, 2), (2009, 1), (2009, 2), (2010, 1))`. The list doesn't have to be sorted. Is it possible to generate this list through the ORM efficiently? The best solution I found is:

```
term_list = set(Lecture.objects.values_list('year', 'term'))
```

But that ORM call still returns a result for every `Lecture` and reduces it in Python, so it could grow slow with a large set of `Lecture`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have all the data in the database, then it will work. but if data is not there, you should generate it yourselves.

```
In [1]: import itertools
In [2]: list(itertools.product((2006,2007,2008), (1,2)))
Out[2]: [(2006, 1), (2006, 2), (2007, 1), (2007, 2), (2008, 1), (2008, 2)]
```

directly from the database (but will not return all the combinations if not in the database):

```
In [1]: from django.db import connection

In [2]: Lecture.objects.values_list('year','term').distinct()
Out[2]: [(2001, 1), (2001, 2), (2002, 1), (2002, 2), (2003, 1), (2003, 2), (2004, 1), (2004, 2)]

In [3]: connection.queries
Out[3]: 
[{'sql': u'SELECT DISTINCT "backend_lecture"."year", "backend_lecture"."term" FROM    "backend_lecture" LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.001'}]
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really help. I only want to list terms that have lectures in the database. My oneliner in the question does that, albeit inefficiently. What I'm looking for is an efficient ORM call that gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a combination of [distinct()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) and values().